# How to connect to libvirt VMs by name, instead of IP address

Tags: fedora, dns, libvirt, firewalld, mdns

I want to connect to my libvirt virtual machines by name.  I used to be able to do that - is it just not possible any more?  I don't really want to muck around with extra manual configuration for each VM.

I used to be able to do e.g. `ssh debian10-vm.local`.  This works using the magic of MDNS / avahi.  But it stopped working at some point :-(.  Currently I am running Fedora Workstation 32.  I think this stopped working in a slightly earlier version.

If I stop `firewalld`, then it works just like it used to.  But I want to keep running the firewall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Install [libvirt-nss](https://libvirt.org/nss.html).  For Fedora, run `dnf install libvirt-nss`.  (For Debian: `apt install libnss-libvirt`).
2. In `/etc/nsswitch.conf`, you want the `hosts:` line to include `libvirt`. There is an example in the link above.
3. You can now access the VM by hostname e.g. `ssh debian10-vm`.  In this solution, you do not use a suffix like `.local`.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Create `/etc/firewalld/zones/libvirt.xml` as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<zone target="ACCEPT">
  <short>libvirt</short>

  <description>
    The default policy of "ACCEPT" allows all packets to/from
    interfaces in the zone to be forwarded, while the (*low priority*)
    reject rule blocks any traffic destined for the host, except those
    services explicitly listed (that list can be modified as required
    by the local admin). This zone is intended to be used only by
    libvirt virtual networks - libvirt will add the bridge devices for
    all new virtual networks to this zone by default.
  </description>

<rule priority='32767'>
  <reject/>
</rule>
<protocol value='icmp'/>
<protocol value='ipv6-icmp'/>
<service name='dhcp'/>
<service name='dhcpv6'/>
<service name='dns'/>
<!-- <service name='ssh'/> --> <!-- Wut? No thank you. -->
<service name='tftp'/>

<service name='mdns'/> <!-- Added by the local admin :). -->
</zone>
```

Step 2: Run `firewall-cmd --reload`

---

There is an explanation why this stuff changed in the libvirt patch, "[selectively install a firewalld 'libvirt' zone](https://github.com/libvirt/libvirt/commit/3b71f2e42dc6c5453d09136578bfb868874da088)".  Apparently it happened when `firewalld` switched from using `iptables` to using `nftables`.